# Why does quicksort exclude the middle element but mergesort includes it?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I was going over the implementation of quicksort (from CLRS 3rd Edition). I found that the recursive divide of the array goes from the low index to middle-1 and then again from middle+1 to high.

```
QUICKSORT(A,p,r)
1 if(p < r)
2        q = PARTITION(A,p,r)
3        QUICKSORT(A,p,q-1)
4        QUICKSORT(A,q+1,r)
```

And the implementation of the merge sort is given as follows:

```
MERGE-SORT(A,p,r)
1 if(p < r)
2       q = (p+r)/2 (floor)
3       MERGE-SORT(A,p,q)
4       MERGE-SORT(A,q+1,r)
5       MERGE(A,p,q,r)
```

As both of them use the divide strategy to be the same, why does quicksort ignore the middle elements as going from `0` to `q-1` and `q+1` to `r` does not have `q` included in it while the mergesort has?

Comment: The partition step puts the pivot at `q`, so that value is at its final location in the array.

Comment: Note this depends on the partition algorithm. [Lomuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) excludes the pivot, while [Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) includes the pivot in one of the partitions. A variation of [Hoare - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLauY6PpjW4), doesn't move the pivot or any values equal to the pivot value.

Answer (score 3):

**Quicksort** puts all the elements smaller than the pivot on one side and all elements bigger on the other side. After this step we know the final position of the pivot will be between those two, and that's where we put it, so we don't need to look at it again.

Thus we can exclude the pivot element in the recursive calls.

**Mergesort** just picks the middle position and doesn't do anything with that element until later. There's no guarantee that the element in that position will already be in the right place, thus we need to look at that element again later on.

Thus we must include the middle element in the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods exploit divide strategy but in different ways

Mergesort (the most common implementation) divides array recursively into equal (if possible) size parts, middle indexes are fixed positions (for given array length). Recurive calls treat left part and right part of array completely.

Quicksort **partition** subroutine places pivot element in the needed (final) position (in most cases pivot index is not middle). There is no need to treat this eleьent further, and recursive calls treat pieces before and after that element.